# Angular PrimeNG p-confirmDialog display twice

Tags: angular, dialog, primeng, display

Which is that case when the confirmation dialog displayed twice?
Or with other aspect, what is the cause when a confirm dialog shown twice?

I have a simple dialog template

```
<p-confirmDialog icon="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"
                 width="444"
                 [closable]="false"
                 key="uniqueidofdialog"
                 appendTo="body"
                 #dialogref>
  <p-footer>
    <button id="gemini_consentLockedByAnotherUser_btnOk"
            type="button"
            pButton
            class="button-primary"
            label="OK"
            (click)="dialogref.accept()"></button>
  </p-footer>
</p-confirmDialog>

  private showConfirmDialog() {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
      message: `Warning! blah-blah.`,
      header: `Warning header`,
      key: 'uniqueidofdialog',
      accept: () => {
        // TODO
      }
    });     
  }
```

Of course the ComfirmationService included into the provider section of the module, and the ComfirmDialogModule is imported into the import section of the module. showConfirmDialog() called once.

What I missed?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 8):

If you did not provide any key, you can also fix this problem providing the `ConfirmationService` for your component only

```js
@Component({
  providers: [ConfirmationService], // <- inject the service at the component level.
  selector: 'your-component',
  styleUrls: ['./your.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './your.component.html',
})
```

Answer (score 4):

That problem is usually caused when multiple confirm dialog have same key.. Thus ensure that your key is unique for your dialog. which i see that you have already done... just double check your codebase for all existing confirm dialog

Comment: Or, if you aren't using keys at all. For me, I had to add a key to my child `p-confirmDialog` to prevent all dialogs from firing because the dialog in the parent also wasn't using a key.